# JaCoCo add missing coverage

Tags: java, jacoco

I'm trying to achieve 100% coverage but SonarQube/JaCoCo says line 7 is not tested.

I did this test to test the main:

```
        try ( MockedStatic<SpringApplication> springApplicationMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic( SpringApplication.class ) )
        {
            ApiApplication.main( new String[] {} );

            springApplicationMockedStatic.verify( () -> SpringApplication.run( ApiApplication.class, new String[] {} ) );
        }
```

How can I fix the missing coverage?

Thanks

[image: Coverage]